# Why can I not use \string to prevent the expansion of \csname?

Tags: tex-core, expansion, auxiliary-files, csname

When writing things to the aux file that should be expanded at the next runs `\begin{document}` call, expansion of those things must be canceled out. This can be done by preceding the active character (`\`) with

1. `\string`
2. `\protect`

Therefore, when writing the macro `\saveForLater` to the aux file, I could do:

```
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\saveForLater{123}}
```

But when I want to write that same macro (control sequence) to the aux file using the `\csname` syntax, I have to use a `\noexpand`

```
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\gdef\noexpand\csname saveForLater@\somedef\string\endcsname{456}}
```

`\string\csname` does not work, yet `\string` works fine (and is required) on the `\endcsname`.

Please explain this.

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\saveForLater{}%init
\def\somedef{HEY}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\saveForLater{123}}
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\gdef\string\csname saveForLater@\somedef\string\endcsname{456}} % DOES NOT WORK
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\gdef\noexpand\csname saveForLater@\somedef\string\endcsname{456}} % WORKS
\end{document}
```

## Uncomment the Line and Behold

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \expandafter\gdef \csnamesaveForLater@HEY
                                         \endcsname{456}
```

## Aux File with Everything Uncommented

(and forcefully exiting due to error)

```
\relax
\gdef\saveForLater{123}
\expandafter\gdef \csnamesaveForLater@HEY\endcsname{456}
\expandafter\gdef \csname saveForLater@HEY\endcsname{456}
```

Comment: Doesn't `\gdef\expandafter\string\csname saveForLater\endcsname` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recall that `\write` does complete expansion until unexpandable tokens remain (when the write operation actually takes place). Since `\gdef` is unexpandable, it needs not be preceded by `\string`, unless you want to avoid a space following it.

There is a timing problem with your code (let me omit `\immediate` that's irrelevant here):

```
\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\gdef\noexpand\csname saveForLater@\somedef\string\endcsname{456}}
```

1. the token `\string` is expandable, so it acts on the following token (`\expandafter`)
2. `\gdef` is not expandable
3. `\noexpand` is expandable, so it acts on the next token (`\csname`)
4. the characters in `saveForLater@` are unexpandable
5. `\somedef` should expand to character tokens, let's say it expands to `foo`
6. `\string` is expandable, so it acts on the next token (`\endcsname`)
7. the characters in `{456}` are unexpandable.

Thus what you get written is

```
\expandafter\gdef \csname saveForLater@foo\endcsname{456}
```

With `\string\csname` you'd get

```
\expandafter\gdef \csnamesaveForLater@foo\endcsname{456}
```

because there is *no* space following `\csname` in the token list passed to `\write`.

Why is there one with `\noexpand`? For the same reason there is one after `\gdef`: TeX adds a space following an unexpandable control word when it performs a write operation. With `\noexpand\csname` the normally expandable `\csname` is made temporarily equivalent to `\relax`, so it gets written with a space following it, just like `\relax` would (or `\gdef`).

```
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
  \gdef\expandafter\noexpand\csname saveForLater@\somedef\endcsname{456}%
}
```

will write

```
\gdef \saveForLater@foo {456}
```

because `\expandafter` causes the control sequence being formed by `\csname` before `\noexpand` can act on it.

If you want to preserve the `\csname` in the `.aux` file:

```
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
  \noexpand\expandafter
  \gdef\noexpand\csname saveForLater@\somedef\endcsname{456}%
}
```

that will write

```
\expandafter \gdef \csname saveForLater@foo\endcsname {456}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\gdef \string\saveForLater{123}}
```

This should work since it saves `\gdef\saveForLater{123}` in the .aux.

```
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\gdef\string\csname saveForLater\string\endcsname{456}}
```

The problem there is that you are saving `\expandafter\gdef \csnamesaveForLater\endcsname{456}` in the .aux, because `\string` doesn't add a space after outputting the control sequence name. So when you read again and see `\csnamesaveForLater` TeX doesn't know what that is. You would need `\string\csname\space`. But I don't know what you intend, simpler seems

```
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\gdef\expandafter\string\csname saveForLater\endcsname{456}}
```

which saves `\gdef\saveForLater{456}`. If that's not what you intend, you need that `\space` there.

Or, as you've already seen, use `\noexpand`.

Comment: I had a similar situation and needed the `\space` because I wanted something like `\expandafter\gdef\csname foo-bar@hello:world\endcsname{1}` in the AUX file. Thanks for pointing that out.