Check if a partial list created with titletoc is empty
I’m using the titletoc package with the memoir class, and I want to conditionally hide the titles of partial lists (e.g., \listtablename) if they are empty. Currently, I have the following setup.
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand*{\afterpartskip}{\startlist{lot}\printlist{lot}{}{\section*{\listtablename}}}

\begin{document}

\part{Part one}

\part{Part two}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Table one}
\end{table}

\end{document}

I don't want a 'List of Tables' heading underneath 'Part one', how can I achieve this? I am using LuaLaTeX as the compiler. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

\IfFileExists{\jobname.lof}{\listoffigures} ?

it looks rather weird to add list formatting to the afterpartskip command, what is the intention here, and also why the low level \startlist rather than the standard \listoffigures ?

do you mean you want to hide the titles if the lists are empty?

Sorry, I'm using partial lists, so I might have two parts at the same time, one with pictures and the other without. Furthermore, when compiling with \startlist{lot}\printlist{lot}{}{\IfFileExists{\jobname.lot}{\chapter*{\listtablename}}} (assuming \jobname.lot exists), it seems to give me errors, then \jobname.lot disappears, then the compilation completes with no errors and the file \jobname.lot reappears, but \listtablename is not printed. I'm not sure why.

@cfr Yes. If empty then replace \chapter*{\listfigurename} with nothing.

as always your question would be a lot clearer, and it would be a lot easier to test answers if you provided an example of the problem not just a fragment.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks for the heads-up, I just updated the problem.

I have found a way with etoc but it is incompatible it seems with using titletoc.

One way would be to write to the .aux file which parts have at least one table. An easy way is to define a command that contains the part number \thepart, and to add this command definition to the table environment hook. Then in the code argument of \printlist you check if the command corresponding to the current part exists. If yes then you print the section title.
MWE:
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/table/before}{\immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\expandafter\noexpand\csname tablepart\thepart\endcsname{\relax}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand*{\afterpartskip}{\startlist{lot}\printlist{lot}{}{%
\ifcsname tablepart\thepart\endcsname%
\section*{\listtablename}%
\else no tables in this part\fi%
}}

\begin{document}
\part{Part one}

\part{Part two}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Table one}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Resulting .aux file:
\relax 
\providecommand*{\memsetcounter}[2]{}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {part}{\partnumberline {I}Part one}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\ttl@writefile{plt}{\ttl@starttoc{default@1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {part}{\partnumberline {II}Part two}{3}{}\protected@file@percent }
\ttl@writefile{plt}{\ttl@stoptoc{default@1}}
\ttl@writefile{plt}{\ttl@starttoc{default@2}}
\gdef \tablepartII {\relax }
\ttl@finishall
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {0.1}{\ignorespaces Table one}}{4}{}\protected@file@percent }
\memsetcounter{lastsheet}{4}
\memsetcounter{lastpage}{4}
\gdef \@abspage@last{4}

Resulting output for part I:

Note that this will only work if the parts are numbered with roman numerals, because there will be bare commands like \gdef\tablepartII{\relax} in the .aux file, which would not work if it was \gdef\tablepart2. You can fix that if needed with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401281/, see the last comment about preserving \csname in the .aux file.
Note also that if you have two or more tables in a part then you will get duplicate \gdef statements in the .aux file, which is not very clean (and you could avoid it with some extra code) but it will still work without warnings or errors because \def overwrites earlier definitions.
